# Логирование в разные файлы

Tags: java, логирование

Есть такой properties файл

```
.level = FINE
my.handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
my.name1.handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
my.name2.handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = my.log.LogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = my.log.LogFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = log_%u.log
```

Вопрос, можно ли как-то развести по разным файлам логи от `my.name1` и `my.name2`?

Или только написанием наследника `FileHandler` с перекрытием метода `publish`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае конфигурацией вы вашу задачу не решите. Если вы конфигурируете логирование Tomcat, то там такая возможность [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3662889/4863012). Если нет - можно этого добиться, сконфигурировав логгеры в Java:

```
Logger log1 = Logger.getLogger("my.name1");
log1.addHandler(new FileHandler("my.name1.log"));
Logger log2 = Logger.getLogger("my.name2");
log2.addHandler(new FileHandler("my.name2.log"));
```

Если есть такая возможность, постарайтесь отказаться от `java.util.logging` в пользу более гибкой библиотеки логирования. В log4j и Logback возможность разводить разные логи в разные файлы есть из коробки. А если вы воспользуетесь slf4j, то сможете при необходимости относительно безболезненно сменить библиотеку логирования, не модифицируя код.